# MVC view unit test visibility of element based on authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm writing an MVC app.

If I have a piece of code:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator")) {
        @Html.DropDownListFor(...)
    }
```

So the dropdownlistfor is only visible or even there for administrators.

How do you unit test that this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do:

- Create a stub for the User object (of type IPrincipal)
- Create a stub for the Request object (of type HttpRequestBase) with the stubbed User object
- Inject the stubbed request object to your request context.

See example below (using Rhino mocks)

```
var CurrentUser = MockRepository.GenerateStub<IPrincipal>();
CurrentUser.Stub(u => u.IsInRole("Administrator")).Return(true);
var context = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpContextBase>();
var requestContext = new RequestContext(context, new RouteData());
var request = MockRepository.GenerateStub<HttpRequestBase>();
context.User = CurrentUser;
context.Stub(c => c.Request).Return(request);
controller = new YourController();
controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext(requestContext, controller);

var view = controller.DoAction() as ViewResult;
```

That would help you setup the controller and the current user with all required roles. 
I personally wouldn't unit test the view as it is supposed to be thin and dump. Most of your stuff should happen in the controller/business layer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to unit test your views, I would suggest checking out [the Razor Single File Generator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/).  This will allow you to pre-compile your views, and to create unit tests as well.